# mc (midnight commander) view (F3) strange behavior when there is a "." in the filename

Tags: linux, nano, mc

It seems to ignore newline characters in "parsed" view. In raw view everything is fine. Same thing happens in nano "justified" mode.

a) parsed text file

[image]

b) same file in raw mode

[image]

c) vi with :set list
[image]

d) same file in parsed mode when the name is changed to "tt"

[image]

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the ., but the .1 . This extension is used for man pages - and so the viewer tries to interpret this as a man page.

Edit: this is controlled by the file [`/etc/mc/mc.ext`](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/077947008d81b2634f2d1d5e607a1c0424b47118/misc/mc.ext.in#L364) - you'll find a

```
# Manual page
regex/(([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])|\.man)$
        Open=/usr/lib/mc/ext.d/text.sh open man %var{PAGER:more}
        View=%view{ascii,nroff} /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/text.sh view man %var{PAGER:more}
```

Entry.

Comment: That's good to know. I thought my results were wrong.
Can you link me to the source of this info so that I can check your answer as valid and move on?

Comment: https://www.opengroup.org/austin/papers/posix_faq.html

Link to 

www.unix-systems.org/version4/

is dead!

Now I don't have a source!

Comment: I've added my source to the answer ;)